# what the difference "백화점" and "편의점" from market in english?

Tags: word-usage, place-names, usage

**안녕 하세요!!**
I have the problem about this. I often hear these two words. I'm still confused to distinguish the two.
Like:

> 백화점 갈래? (Do you want to go to market?)

or

> 편의점 갈래?

what the difference between both?
**감사합니다!!!** greetings from Indonesia!

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of shopping places that are common.
Sometimes translations don't tell you all; certainly,  백화점 is definitely not a market.  It should be translated "department store".  But it's good to know more about them.  Department store (백화점) in Korea are generally high-class and expensive.

Here are some of the most common types of stores you'll encounter in Korea:

- 백화점: as mentioned above: department store, usually high-end and
  expensive
- 편의점: convenience store
- 시장: market, usually outdoors, sometimes covered but still outdoors.  Cheap.
- 마트:a supermarket (though it can be very small); usually specializes in food but sells
  other common things as well
- 대형마트: very large supermarket
- 아웃렛 (sometimes you hear 아울렛): Outlet Mall; large mall that allows brand
  name stores to sell directly; it's supposed to be cheaper there.